# neuroph studio 2.92 not showing neuroph project option

Tags: java, machine-learning, neural-network

I installed neuroph studio 2.92 for windows 64bit but the neuroph project option is not showing when i want to create a new project. All other categories like java, maven are showing. Has anyone encounter similar problem? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue with version 2.9 , currently I am using version 2.8 as a work around

Comment: Try to goto tools->plugins->installed plugins
and check whether all the neuroph related plugins are active

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It can be solved my doing following steps:

1. Open Neuroph Studio and go to tools/plugins
2. Then go to installed section and sort the plugins into active/inavtive mode
3. activate all the inactive plugins and you are done.